# Count the number of element present in the inner list

Tags: c#, linq

```cs
public Class Users
{
    string UserName,
    List<UserDesktop> userDesktop
}

public class UserDesktop
{
    int ID,
    string DesktopName,
    string type -- here Type value is A, B;
}
```

Here I have to find the users count having desktop assigned of type A
Users variable containing all data.

```cs
List<Users> finalUsers = users.Count(s=>s.userDesktop.where(x=>x.type == "A"))
```

Please let me know the correct way of doing it.

Comment: 1) change `Where` to `Any` and 2) Count returns an integer and not a list. you have the wrong type on the left hand side

Answer (score 8):

You might want to use SelectMany to flatten the list then count it:

```
int numberOfUsersWithDesktopOfTypeA = users.SelectMany(u => u.userDesktop)
                                           .Count(ud => ud.type == "A");
```

If you want the list of users that have an A desktop:

```
var usersWithDesktopA = Users.Where(u => u.Any(ud => ud.type == "A"));
var numberOfUsersWithDesktopA = usersWithDesktopA.Count();
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please help here to get a distinct user desktop? Currently one user have multiple desktop of type A, that should release one user

Answer (score 3):

To query the user(s) who has `UserDesktop` of type 'A':

```
List<Users> hasDesktopAUsers = users.Where(u => u.userDesktop.Any(ud => ud.type == "A"))
        .ToList();
```

Next, you can get the number of count from the previous result as:

```
int numberOfDesktopAUsers = hasDesktopAUsers.Count;
```

### Out of topic:

It is recommended to have a proper naming convention for handling single and plural terms to avoid confusion. For example:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<UserDesktop> UserDesktops { get; set; }
}

public class UserDesktop
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DesktopName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

From the above, you should name as `User` as it is an `User` object while `UserDesktops` with 's' as it is a collection set.

Final solution:

```
List<User> hasDesktopAUsers = users.Where(u => u.UserDesktops.Any(ud => ud.Type == "A"))
    .ToList(); 
int numberOfDesktopAUsers = hasDesktopAUsers.Count;
```

Comment: It is better to write `int` instead of `var` in this case.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević how so?

Comment: @sommmen When you write code for yourself, write as you want. When you are explaining and you see that OP made mistake with type in that line, include that in the answer.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević Much obliged for explaining!

Comment: Hi @sommmen, thanks for the suggestion and I had included it in the solution for better understanding.